# Should methods that accept a UnitOfWork parameter be made static?

Tags: c#, resharper

In my Controller, I'll have methods like this:

```
public ActionResult GetItemsFromServiceLayer(someValue)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(ApplicationDbContext)
    {
        var result = Service.GetItems(unitOfWork, someValue);

        return View("SomeView", result);
    }
}
```

Which calls on this method in my Service layer:

```
public List<ItemViewModel> GetItems(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, string someValue)
{
    var listOfItems = unitOfWork.ItemRepo.GetSpecificSetOfItems(someValue).ToList();

    foreach(var item in listOfItems)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }

    return listOfItems;
}
```

ReSharper is always suggesting that I should change my Service layer methods, `GetItems`, to `static`, which has me thinking less about if I should or not, but more about if it would be safe to.

By making this static could I expect to run into weird connection errors when multiple users are trying to access the same method, or would I be in the clear here because the `UnitOfWork` is sent as a parameter and not shared instance?

Comment: R# does this suggestion because the method doesn't deal with instance members. So making the method static will not end up with weird bugs.

Comment: There's a negligible performance difference in static versus non static methods. However - making it static, should not cause any issues.

Another issue is - your data access layer is leaking into your controller layer. Ideally your unit of work should be injected through a constructor using a container using per request/scoped registration.

Comment: I'd also pass your unit of work into the constructor since it seems like your are going to need it for your class to actually work.  If you store it in an instance variable and reference it there, R# will stop hounding you.

Comment: @SimonKatanski, I'm not following you, which constructor are you taking about in this case, the Service constructor? Do you have any resources that could explain that idea further?

Comment: @Fran, are you talking about the same thing as Simon?

Comment: @RyanTaite design wise your service layer should depend on your DAL layer. And your controllers should have a dependency on your services. 
You'd need to look into working with IOC containers. Here's an example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: I'll read into this, thank you for the insight!

Comment: "ReSharper is always suggesting that I should" - are you sure? Is it offering you a [Quick Fix](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Quick-Fixes.html)? Or is it in fact offering you a [*Context Action*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Context_Actions.html) to *allow* you to quickly change it to static, **if you want to**?